# How to integrate noimage picture in this code

Tags: php, themes, plugin-gd-star-rating

How can i integrate a image if there is no attached image?

I'm using this code with success to integrate no-image picture if is no picture is attached to post.

```
<?php
if ( ! $img = get_field('img_actor', $post_object->ID ) )
    $img = '/wp-content/uploads/noimage1.jpg';
?>
<img class="actor_img" src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo urlencode($img); ?>&h=70&w=50&zc=1"
```

Ok for this, but how can I integrate this code into my GD Star Rating code.
Gd Star Rating is a plugin that rate's the posts - [GD Star Rating](http://www.dev4press.com/plugins/gd-star-rating/)

```
foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
    if ($widget["image_from"] == "content") {

$row->image = gdFunctionsGDSR::get_image_from_text($row->post_content);
    } 
else if ($widget["image_from"] == "custom") {

$post_custom_id = get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_custom"], true);
$row->image = get_bloginfo('url')."/scripts/timthumb.php?src=".get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-content/uploads/".get_post_meta($post_custom_id,"_wp_attached_file",true)."&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1";

    }
                            }
```

The link for full code https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/code/t2/render.php

How i add in a page to display the count of posts.

```
<?php 
wp_gdsr_render_rating_results(array('template_id' => 48, 'rows' => 1, 'select' => 'persoane', 'min_votes' => 0, 'min_count' => 0, 'excerpt_words' => 0, 'image_from' => 'custom', 'image_custom' => 'img_actor', 'image_resize_x' => 55, 'image_resize_y' => 70, 'publish_days' => 1, 'rating_size' => '12', 'review_size' => '12', 'rating_thumb_size' => '12'));
?>
```

Comment: yes but i need to display it, can you help me s_ha_dum ?
please see the image how it display http://s23.postimg.org/yer9yk88b/image.jpg

Comment: What is $widget["image_from"] equal to in your first code snippet?

Comment: image from a custom field, please see the full code Line 138 - 143"https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/code/t2/render.php"

Comment: That link is not working. Is it equal to "custom"?

Comment: sorry for that i put it in the question, please see the updated text.

Comment: Okay. Does this line of code work? Does it return the correct ID?
$post_custom_id = get_post_meta( $row->post_id, $widget['image_custom'], true );

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9703/discussion-between-batman-and-charles-clarkson)

Comment: yes but the image is not display-ing please see the text updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
else if ($widget["image_from"] == "custom") {

    $post_custom_id = get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_custom"], true);
    $row->image = get_bloginfo('url')."/scripts/timthumb.php?src=".get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-content/uploads/".get_post_meta($post_custom_id,"_wp_attached_file",true)."&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1";

}
```

To this:

```
} else if ( 'custom' == $widget['image_from'] ) {

    $post_custom_id = get_post_meta( $row->post_id, $widget['image_custom'], true );

    if ( get_post_meta( $post_custom_id, '_wp_attached_file', true ) )
        $row->image = get_bloginfo('url') . '/scripts/timthumb.php?src=' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/uploads/' . get_post_meta( $post_custom_id, '_wp_attached_file', true ) . '&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1';
    else
        $row->image = get_bloginfo('url') . '/scripts/timthumb.php?src=' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/uploads/noimage1.jpg&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very rough but if you want to add the image when this-- `get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_custom"], true);`-- is empty, the following should do it. You need to change `test_meta` to whatever `$widget["image_custom"]` is.

```
function alter_meta_wpse_106998($a, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
  if ('test_meta' === $meta_key) {

    $meta_type = 'post';

    $meta_cache = wp_cache_get($object_id, $meta_type . '_meta');

    if ( !$meta_cache ) {
      $meta_cache = update_meta_cache( $meta_type, array( $object_id ) );
      $meta_cache = $meta_cache[$object_id];
    }

    if ( empty($meta_cache[$meta_key]) ) {
      $meta_cache[$meta_key][] = site_url('/wp-content/uploads/noimage1.jpg');
    }

    if ( !$meta_key ) {
      return $meta_cache;
    }

    if ( isset($meta_cache[$meta_key]) ) {
      if ( $single ) {
        return maybe_unserialize( $meta_cache[$meta_key][0] );
      } else {
        return array_map('maybe_unserialize', $meta_cache[$meta_key]);
      }
    }

    if ($single) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return array();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
add_filter('get_post_metadata','alter_meta_wpse_106998',1,4);
```

If you look at that code, it is largely a rebuild of [`get_metadata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L267) and borrows heavily from that function.